# CentOS 6 and locale error

Tags: centos, centos6, localization

I just installed CentOS 6 and whenever I login to the system via SSH remotely, I get the following error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8)
```

When I type "locale" on the command line, I get the following output:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

What can be the problem? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: your solution of commenting out the SendEnv LANG LC_* arg worked for me on Mac OS X 10.7.5

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On the server you ssh from do you have a locale set via an environment variable?  In looking at my CentOS 6 installation, the only locale that I can find supported is identified as `en_US.utf8` (discovered using `locale -a` command).   Could this be the problem?

In my testing, when I set the `LC_ALL` environment variable to `en_US.UTF-8`, ssh'd to the server, the output of my locale command was set to `POSIX` in my case. This the same as when I have NOT set (i.e. unset) the `LC_ALL` variable before ssh'ing.

When I set my `LC_ALL` variable to `en_US.utf8` or `en_US.utf-8`, ssh'd to my CentOS 6 box, the output of the locale was the same as what was set on the source box.

Notice I used no caps for UTF also.

Comment: By the way, I noticed that this was occurring from my Mac OS X Lion ssh settings. I edited /etc/ssh_config file and commented SendEnv LANG LC_*. It solved my problem.

Comment: @Cem Thanks for the tip, this indeed fixes it on Mac OS X Lion.

Answer (score 18):

Solved this by disabling "Set locale environment variables on startup" in Terminal Settings > Advanced as per this screenshot.

[image]

NOTE:
If you use iTerm2 you can disable the "Set locale variables automatically" option in Preferences > Profiles > Terminal

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically, Terminal.app was setting "LC_CTYPE=UTF-8" which then caused the errors reported by the OP. Alternatively, `unset LC_CTYPE` or `export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8` fixup the problem after login.

Comment: This solved it for me, thx

Answer (score 12):

#### Simple way:

Add

```
 LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`.

Comment: It works for me, after so many tries.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding a symlink in the CentOS server like this:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8 /usr/lib/locale/UTF-8
```

Once you do that commands like this work:

```
export LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

If you don't, this last command fails with this error:

```
-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory
```

Now, an even simpler solution is just adding this line to /etc/bashrc in the server:

```
export LC_CTYPE="en_US.utf8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! this worked really great. Finally able to remove that annoying comment...

Answer (score 2):

I've got this specific message, when login from a Solaris X to a Centos host.

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

The problem is coming from 2 settings:

1. In my default system ssh_config, I ask the system to pass those variable.

Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES

2. On my source host, thoses settings was set this way:

   SOURCE#
   LANG=
   LC_CTYPE=fr_FR.UTF-8
   LC_NUMERIC=fr_FR.UTF-8
   LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
   LC_COLLATE=fr_FR.UTF-8
   LC_MONETARY=fr_FR.UTF-8
   LC_MESSAGES=fr.UTF-8
   LC_ALL=

But, as you can see, the LC_MESSAGES, is set to fr.UTF-8, which is not an option on my destination host.

```
 DEST#locale -a | grep fr_FR
 fr_FR
 fr_FR@euro
 fr_FR.iso88591
 fr_FR.iso885915@euro
 fr_FR.utf8
```

The problem was solved forcing on my source host, on .bash_profile:
#
     export LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
     export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8

I could have solved it by asking my dest host not to take this variable from any ssh connection (generally, or by creating a locale ssh_config file for my user)

Answer (score 1):

This was my fix in the past for locale errors.

Run the following:
locale-gen

Then edit /etc/locale.gen. Make sure the following is uncommented:

```
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8  
en_US ISO-8859-1  

generate locale

locale-gen
```

Answer (score 1):

On a local Centos 6.2 system:
This did not help:

```
localedef -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

This worked:

```
localedef --no-archive -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

I also deleted `locale-archive` in `/usr/lib/locale`. I do not know if this was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

With **Iterm2**, is different.
Go to `Iterm2 -> Preferences`, Then Go to `Profiles` tab, and choose the `Terminal` tab from the bottom.
Go to `Environment` category, and unmark;

> Set locale variables automatically

Finally, close and start a new session.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

and make sure 
`LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` is in or added to the /etc/sysconifg/i18n

example content

```
LANG="en_GB.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

On my CentOS 8 (minimal server installation) I successfully set my locale variables like this.

Either

```
echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"' > /etc/locale.conf
```

OR

```
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.utf8"' > /etc/locale.conf
```

Relogon and call `locale` to verify the result.

Answer (score -3):

edit `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`

Change `LANG="us"` to `LANG="en_US"`

Save and exit, log out and back in.